# How can JsonIgnore be applied on the constructor

Tags: java, jackson

As per the javadoc of com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore, the target can be the constructor

However I am unable to understand the need to apply this on the constructor i.e

```
  public static class EventTimestamp implements Comparable<EventTimestamp>{
  private static final Long ZERO = new Long(0);

  private Long milliseconds;
  private Long nanoseconds;

  public EventTimestamp() {
     this(System.currentTimeMillis(), System.nanoTime() % 1_000_000_000);
  }

  @JsonIgnore
  public EventTimestamp(long milliseconds) {
     this(milliseconds, 0L);
  }
```

Is this the wrong example?

Comment: why do you want to add @JsonIgnore on constructor? as it is usually used on class field.

Comment: I agree. However from the javadoc, the target for the annotation was specified as constructor as well. Hence I was wondering what the exact usage should be